# Using SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I am using Xamarin and I have modified the Google Maps API 2 sample to use `SupportMapFragment` objects rather than `MapFragment` objects.

Can I have some help with the `InitMapFragment` function.

Here is the code:

```
private void InitMapFragment()
{
    _mapFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment;
    if (_mapFragment == null)
    {
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
            .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
            .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
            .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

        FragmentTransaction fragTx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        _mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
        fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapWithOverlay, _mapFragment, "map");
        fragTx.Commit();
    }
}
```

`_mapFragment` used to be of type `MapFragment`, but now is `SupportMapFragment`.

Also, the activity is inheriting from `Activity` at the moment, should this be `FragmentActivity`, or something else?

Here are the errors that I am getting:

> Error CS0039: Cannot convert type 'Android.App.Fragment' to
>   'Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment' via a reference conversion,
>   boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null
>   type conversion
>
> Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment' to 'Android.App.Fragment'

I am pretty sure that I need to use a `SupportFragmentManager` rather than a `FragmentManager`, yet would like some help please.

**EDIT**

When trying to use SupportFragmentManager, I am getting the following error:

> Error CS0103: The name 'SupportFragmentManager' does not exist in the
>   current context

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're correct - you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() and use that to get the SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: I've never used Xamarin but it looks like things are a bit different there, e.g. there's no getSupportFragmentManager(). This link might help http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14731/fragment-support-fragment-manager-does-not-exist-in-current-context - I'd start with this: Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SupportFramgentManager is inherited from FragmentActivity so make sure the activity extends FragmentActivity. Then modify your code as follows:

```
private void InitMapFragment()
{
    _mapFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("map") as SupportMapFragment;
    if (_mapFragment == null)
    {
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
            .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
            .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
            .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);

        FragmentTransaction fragTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        _mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);
        fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapWithOverlay, _mapFragment, "map");
        fragTx.Commit();
    }
}
```