# How to get access to getSupportFragmentManager or SupportFragmentManager in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

The name 'getSupportFragmentManager' does not exist in the current context

My Code:

```
using Android.Views;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using com.refractored;
using Android.Support.V4.View;

namespace XamarinStore
{
    public class HomeFragment : Android.App.Fragment
    {
        BadgeDrawable basketBadge;
        int badgeCount;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            RetainInstance = true;
            SetHasOptionsMenu(true);



            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var HomePage = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomeLayout, container, false);

            var pager = HomePage.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
            pager.Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);


            var tabs = HomePage.FindViewById<PagerSlidingTabStrip>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            tabs.SetViewPager(pager);

            return HomePage;
        }
    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private  string[] Titles = {"Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
            "Top New Free", "Trending"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        {
        }

        public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted (int position)
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String (Titles [position]);
        }
        #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter
        public override int Count {
            get {
                return Titles.Length;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region implemented abstract members of FragmentPagerAdapter
        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem (int position)
        {
            return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.NewInstance (position);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

How to get access to getSupportFragmentManager in fragment ..

I'am using xamarin cross platform development tool.. with the help of sample project from this source `https://xamarin.com/c-sharp-shirt`

In the demo project if **BackStackEntryCount** count equals to zero it switch screen to another fragment.. so i replaced code with new homefragment i decided to add tabs in the that.. so i tried to use this component "Material Pager Sliding Tab Strip" .. while using that component it stops with this error.
**the name 'getSupportFragmentManager' does not exist in the current context**

> http://components.xamarin.com/view/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: @Harry The name 'getActivity' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I removed comment see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604536/using-supportmapfragment-instead-of-mapfragment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First i inherit `HomeFragment` to `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`

Then i used `ChildFragmentManager` instead of `SupportFragmentManager`

```
pager.Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using FragmentManager = Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager;


public class YourFragment : Fragment
{
//...

//To access to FragmentManager use base.FragmentManager
//Example:
base.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
    .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
        .Commit();

//...
}
```

The first two lines (using...) are very useful if
you work only with Fragment and FragmentManager from Support
and you have clear about not mixing them with normal Fragment and FragmentManager.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Android you should be able to access this using  `FragmentManager` and you need to inherit from  `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`
like so:

```
 public class HomeFragment :  Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
 {
    BadgeDrawable basketBadge;
    int badgeCount;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RetainInstance = true;
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true);

        var count =  FragmentManager.BackStackEntryCount;

        // Create your fragment here
    }
```

`getActivity` 's equivalent in Xamarin is `Activity` (when used in a class that inherits from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` for example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with **Xamarin** but in native android development you cannot access `FragmentManager` from a `Fragment` using `getFragmentManager` or `getSupportFragmentManager` methods. From **API 17** you can call `getChildFragmentManager` method to get a `FragmentManager` instance that allows you to manage fragments from another fragment.

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(...).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Answer (score 0):

public class HomeFragment : FragmentActivity

Extend your class using  FragmentActivity  will solve your problem